# How would I run a separate program within a Python-based window?

Tags: python, window, desktop-application, desktop

I've been trying to figure out for a couple months now how to run a window from another program in a Python window.

The idea here is that I'm attempting to combine two separate programs into one window interface as an application to be run on a desktop computer.

Right now, I can run the programs by using a command line library for Python, but I can't for the life of me find anyway to get it running in a Python window, and was hoping someone could point me to a library for something similar.

Comment: What do you mean by _Python window_?

Comment: I created a basic gui in Python with PySimpleGUI, and what I want to have happen is in the window that creates (or something similar, I can always re-write the gui code), I want a window from a separate program to appear there, instead of in its own standalone window.